# Add to Silverlight project service reference with non async generate operations

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I try to consume WCF service in Silverlight project but in ass Reference dialog windows i can't unchecked "Generate asynchronous operations" :/
Why I can't use non asynchronous in SL? When I add service reference to Console App I can unchecked it.

I need non asynchronous, cause in Console consume works ok, but in SL app I have error when use asynchronous methods :/

Please help ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use synchronous operations because such operations rely on the underlying APIs such as `HttpWebRequest` to also support synchronous operations.  Silverlight versions of these only have asynchronous versions hence everything else has to by asynchronous as well.